# Create string without repeating the same element jn the string (Matlab)

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string "FDFACCFFFBDCGGHBBCFGE" . Could anyone help me to generate a new string with the same order but no element inside repeated twice. Thanks !

The expected output should be like this : "FDACBGHE"

Comment: Show the code you have written, and you will get better help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) with the `'stable'`option:

```
str = 'FDFACCFFFBDCGGHBBCFGE';
result = unique(str, 'stable');
```

If you want something more manual: use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to build a logical index of the elements that haven't appeared (`~any(...)`) earlier (`triu(..., 1)`):

```
result = str(~any(triu(bsxfun(@eq, str, str.'), 1)));
```

Comment: Probably the most elegant solution to this problem.